# Track inventory for add custom options in add simple product

Tags: magento

I want to track inventory for the product shirt have 2 different sizes and 2 colors. So that i can manage stock for both of that simultaneously.

Comment: OK, that's great, but what is your question? Do you want to know how to do this with code, or in the admin interface?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand you either, but why can't you create simple products for all four items and group them with a configurable product? Be sure that stock management is enabled on all four.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, thats not implemented and won't be implemented in near future.

See this [bugreport](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=3650) and this [forum topic](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/13934/P0/). There are a few pointers to solutions in the forum.